# Use webpack and react can't hot update in PHP laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, webpack

Use webpack and react can't hot update in PHP laravel framework?

just manual compiled refresh.

if i visited http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/, show CAN'T GET.i don't kown why?

if i Use webpack and react not in PHP laravel framework. Everything Was All Right.

this is my package.json and webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: [
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js/asset/test.js'),
    ],
    output: {
        path: './public/js/home',
        filename: "index.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets:['react','es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=25000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: please post you code not picture

Comment: I have developed a Laravel Elixir plugin just for this purpose.
Here is the plugin - [laravel-elixir-react-hmr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-react-hmr)  
Here is a demo application - [laravel-elixir-react-hmr-demo](https://github.com/eumentis/laravel-elixir-react-hmr-demo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, I found this quite simple actually.

1. Open webpack.mix.js and add at the bottom:

   `mix.browserSync('localhost:8000');`

The parameter inside depend on your php artisan serve url and port.

2. Run `npm run watch` to install dependency needed for browserSync method.
3. Run `php artisan serve` and `npm run watch` (on different cmd)

Hope this help.

Don't forget to give applause if it is work.

source: https://medium.com/@michael.tandio/easy-setup-hot-loader-for-react-laravel-with-laravel-mix-8f68a1393624